# IMultiValueConverter that ConvertBack value (string) to an array compatible with the types given in targetTypes (WPF)

Tags: wpf, imultivalueconverter

I would like to write a IMultiValueConverter that converts back value (string) to an array with objects compatible with the types given in targetTypes parameter, as so:

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        List<object> results = new List<object>();
        string[] arr = value.ToString().Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            object item = (targetTypes[i])arr[i]; //ERROR: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
        }
        return results.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, for example "London 22" I would like to convert back to "London" (string) and "2" (int). As indicated by the list of types in the targetTypes parameter. And of course, return it as an array.

**However, I am not able to cast elements of this array to expected by the targetTypes parameter, as I commented in the code above.**

*The goal is of course to solve the problem reported during binding: "Can not save the value from target back to source.", Which occurs when an attempt is made to store the string to the int.*

*Which is reported when I use such a converter:*

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return value.ToString().Split(' ');
    }
    else
    {
      return   null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
public object[] ConvertBack(
    object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var strings = value.ToString().Split(' ');

    if (strings.Length != targetTypes.Length)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid number of substrings");
    }

    return strings
            .Select((s, i) => System.Convert.ChangeType(s, targetTypes[i]))
            .ToArray();
}
```